# Building flutter release android app failed

Tags: firebase, flutter

I recently started building flutter apps and just finished my first project, a google play like app store using firebase, it works fine in debug mode but when I tried to build a release apk it fails with: `firebase_analytics:verifyReleaseResources` message.

I tried changing the firebase dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` to ones before AndroidX and also tried running flutter clean but nothing worked.

Here are my dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^0.3.0

  firebase_analytics: ^1.1.0

  firebase_storage: ^2.1.1+2

  firebase_database: ^1.0.5
  store_redirect: ^1.0.1

  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.8

  firebase_auth: ^0.9.0
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.4

  rxdart: 0.20.0

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.0
```

And here is the error I get when I run flutter run --release

```
Initializing gradle...                                              1.3s

Resolving dependencies...                                           4.6s

Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO CX Air in release mode...

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_analytics:verifyReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  C:\Projects\flutterExcersice\NestedTabs-master\flutternestedtabsapp\build\firebase_analytics\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:276: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Projects\flutterExcersice\NestedTabs-master\flutternestedtabsapp\build\firebase_analytics\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:277: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      23.5s

Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late reply, but posting it for future users.

I also faced same error. That too in release build, debug build is working fine.

After updating all the firebase and google libraries, it started working.
I updated all these libraries:-

- firebase_core: ^0.4.2
- firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
- firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1
- cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10+2
- firebase_messaging: ^6.0.1
- google_sign_in: ^4.0.14

Comment: $flutter build appbundle command is throwing following error [Fatal Error] checker-qual-2.5.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':admob_flutter'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':admob_flutter:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.checkerframework:checker-qual:2.5.2.
     Required by:
         project :admob_flutter > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.3.0 > com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre